# 2 images to appear while the status is active

Tags: angularjs, html, css

I have this screen: [image: the red flag appears when the status is active]
I want the screen to look like [image: this]
so the motorcycle will appear also with the red flag when the status is active
The code: 
HTML

```
                                                    <a class="" ng-class="{'myflicker':orderInfo.status==orderStat.order_status}">

                                                        <div class="logoMove" aria-hidden="true"></div>
                                                    </a>
                                                    <div class="map "></div>

                                                    <div class="triggerName">
                                                        {{orderStat.order_status_display}}
                                                    </div>
                                                </li>
                                            <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                            </ul>

                                    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.tracker .active a {
    background-image: url(../images/flag_red.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    border: 0px solid #A52A2A;
```

The image is inside here:

```
.li.a.logoMove{
    background-image: url(../images/moto.png);

    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    left: 0;
    transition: all 2s;
}
```

But image is not showing right. Why is that?

Comment: I can't make any sense of your code. Those don't show the complete picture and we cannot see the issue in action. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @HerrSerker simply, I want to know how to add the motorcycle with CSS

Comment: I think the problem lies with the selector `.li.a.logoMove` means: 'Any element which has a class of 'li' and 'a' and 'logoMove'. I think you meant `li a .logoMove` which means any element with the class 'logoMove' which has an anchor tag (`<a>`) as ancestor which has a list item anchor (`<li>`) as ancestor

Answer (score 0):

When you position something as absolute , you have to give it `z-index` . Try giving the picture you want to be shown a `z-index: 1;` . Tell me if this does anything.

Comment: thank you. I did it under `.logoMove` but the moto appears also when the status is not active. when I do it under `.logoMovee.active a{`
 nothing apears

Comment: Maybe you can than use JS and make an `if`. `If` it has active , give it `z-index : 1` , if it doesn't have active , `z-index :0` or `z-index : -1`. You can also give the image `display:none`/`display:block` . That is up to you :)

Comment: I prefer to use CSS only

Comment: if it possible.